# r visNetwork node position issue

Tags: r, layout, nodes, graph-visualization, visnetwork

I am creating graph structure

```
id    <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
label <- c("All", "Cat", "Dog", "Rice","Fish", "Bread","Rice","Fish", "Bread")

nodes <- data.frame(id, label)

edges <- data.frame(
from = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
to = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
  )



visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%",height = "800px") %>%  visNodes(shape = "square") %>% 
  visEdges(arrows = "to") %>% 
  visInteraction(navigationButtons = TRUE)%>% 
  visHierarchicalLayout(levelSeparation = 200) %>% 
  visOptions(manipulation = TRUE)
```

expecting it to show up like this.

[image: Expected Output]

However the actual output is like this

[image: Actual Output]

The node positions are incorrect , I cannot manually move the nodes and this makes it very hard to explain. Need help rearranging the nodes based on the expected output above.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that `cat` and `dog` connect to the same `rice`, `fish`, `bread` nodes.

Comment: @emilliman5, ah you are right, I had the same feeling. I have updated my question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the level for each node to get the orientation you want.

```
library(visNetwork)
id    <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
label <- c("All", "Cat", "Dog", "Rice","Fish", "Bread","Rice","Fish", "Bread")

nodes <- data.frame(id, label, level = c( 1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3))

edges <- data.frame(
  from = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  to = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
)

visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%",height = "800px") %>%  visNodes(shape = "square") %>% 
  visEdges(arrows = "to") %>% 
  visInteraction(navigationButtons = TRUE)%>% 
  visHierarchicalLayout(levelSeparation = 200) %>% 
  visOptions(manipulation = TRUE)
```

[image]